# Is Ruby pipe streaming asynchronous?

Tags: ruby, streaming, pipe

I have a [map/reduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) streaming [pipeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29) written in Ruby which is behaving strangely. The pipeline looks like this:

`mapper | sort | reducer | expander | sort | splitter | uploader`

The mapper writes to STDOUT (via [puts](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-puts)), the reducer reads from STDIN (via [ARGF.each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ARGF.html#method-i-each)) and writes to STDOUT (via puts) etc. etc.

It seems like when the uploader is executed the files the splitter should've have created are not created yet. So the uploader doesn't upload anything.

Here's my Pipeline class:

```
class Pipeline

  def run(context)
    raise ArgumentError, 'context is nil' unless context
    raise ArgumentError, 'context[:logger] is nil' unless context[:logger]

    current_path = File.dirname(__FILE__)
    mapper       = File.join(current_path, 'mapper.rb')
    reducer      = File.join(current_path, 'reducer.rb')
    expander     = File.join(current_path, 'expander.rb')
    splitter     = File.join(current_path, 'splitter.rb')
    uploader     = File.join(current_path, 'uploader.rb')

    mapper_args = context[:order_id] == nil ? nil : " #{context[:order_id]}"

    command_line = "ruby #{mapper}#{mapper_args} | sort | ruby #{reducer} | ruby #{expander} | sort | ruby #{splitter} | ruby #{uploader}"

    context[:logger].debug command_line

    %x{#{command_line}}
  end

end
```

If piped streaming is asynchronous in Ruby, I'm wondering if doing what RubyMine does would fix this.  For example, before they run a Ruby script they prepend the command line like this:  `ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift)`.

I've updated my code with this technique, however, I want to know if this is correctly.  Or, if there is a better way?

```
class Pipeline

  def run(context)
    raise ArgumentError, 'context is nil' unless context
    raise ArgumentError, 'context[:logger] is nil' unless context[:logger]

    current_path = File.dirname(__FILE__)
    ruby         = 'ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift)'
    mapper       = File.join(current_path, 'mapper.rb')
    reducer      = File.join(current_path, 'reducer.rb')
    expander     = File.join(current_path, 'expander.rb')
    splitter     = File.join(current_path, 'splitter.rb')
    uploader     = File.join(current_path, 'uploader.rb')

    mapper_args = context[:order_id] == nil ? nil : " #{context[:order_id]}"

    create_reports_command_line = "#{ruby} #{mapper}#{mapper_args} | sort | #{ruby} #{reducer} | #{ruby} #{expander} | sort | #{ruby} #{splitter}"

    context[:logger].debug create_reports_command_line

    %x{#{create_reports_command_line}}

    sleep 60 # Sleep for 1 min, just in case...

    upload_reports_command_line = "#{ruby} #{uploader}"

    context[:logger].debug upload_reports_command_line

    %x{#{upload_reports_command_line}}
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable `sync`. That tells Ruby to *not* buffer the output, but instead send it as it's output.

> Sets the “sync mode” to true or false. When sync mode is true, all output is immediately flushed to the underlying operating system and is not buffered internally.

Pipelines should work with `sync` disabled/false, but you won't see anything until the first, then subsequent pipes, see a closed input, or they have full buffers and flush them, which could take a while.

See [`IO.sync=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-i-sync-3D) for more information.